Java Spring Boot 2.11 won't use TLS 1.3 for outbound connection to API
I have an API I'm trying to do an integration with, and the API only supports TLSv1.3. I've tried a number of different strategies for connecting with no real changes and hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Here is a sample bit of code to illustrate my issue:
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String apiUrl = "https://api-url.com";

        try {
            // Create an SSLContext with TLS 1.3
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3");
            sslContext.init(null, null, null);

            // Create an HttpClient with the SSLContext
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                    .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
                    .sslContext(sslContext)
                    .build();

            // Create an HttpRequest
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(URI.create(apiUrl))
                    .GET()
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    .build();

            // Send the request and retrieve the response
            HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

            // Process the response
            if (response.statusCode() == 200) {
                String responseBody = response.body();
                System.out.println("Response Body: " + responseBody);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Request failed. Status code: " + response.statusCode());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


This code works when it's a standalone application, connects successfully to the API. When I take this same code, and place it into a service in my spring boot application, it fails with an ssl handshake failure:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:130)

at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)

at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:365)

at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:287)

at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:204)

at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)

at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1507)

I can see the ClientHello when I have debugging enabled and it's clearly sending TLSv1.2:
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|F6|XNIO-1 task-1|2024-04-03 23:07:47.320 EDT|ClientHello.java:640|Produced ClientHello handshake message (

"ClientHello": {

"client version" : "TLSv1.2",

"random" : "FDA9B3D29A6C9F53E773999AFB00B22C4CB2D6103266BDE2B783DF2CBC8A82BA",

"session id" : "A60300E77225F0C6A66FF1D40A90ED38CBC5559DF77BCF7EC5E7A65999109417",

"cipher suites" : "[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302), TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301), TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0x1303)]",

"compression methods" : "00",


Using OpenSSL to connect from my terminal, I can see that TLSv1.3 is required
SSL handshake has read 2632 bytes and written 418 bytes

Verification: OK

---

New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

Server public key is 256 bit

This TLS version forbids renegotiation.

Compression: NONE

Expansion: NONE

No ALPN negotiated

Early data was not sent

Verify return code: 0 (ok)

---

I've verified using System.GetProperty that both jdk.tls.client.protocols and https.protocols are not set, so it's using the defaults. I've also tried setting both of them to TLSv1.3 and it still uses 1.2 when making a request.
This application also uses Java 11 which I've confirmed supports TLSv1.3 by default, I've also ran it using Java 22 (which to my surprise actually ran) but I have the same issue there as well.
I'm a bit rusty on Java, and not SUPER familiar with spring boot in general, but is there something I'm missing here to get this thing to use TLSv1.3 when making an outbound connection?

AFAIK the spring boot version should be mostly irrelevant here, it's more important what JDK version you use. Also: be super careful about deciding what TLS version is used based on the initial handshake, because that stuff is confusing: TLSv 1.3 requires some places to claim to be 1.2 and others to report ability to speak 1.3, so just because in one place it says "1.2" doesn't mean it's 1.2: See here for an explanation.

That makes sense, and I see that happening in the standalone application. Is there a more in depth way to debug this? In the standalone app with debugging on, I can immediately see the ServerHello, and the rest of the negotiation where TLSv1.3 is negotiated. Inside of the spring boot app though, after the ClientHello it just gets an alert of the handshake failure and no additional information to go on.

Thanks to Steffen Ullrich over on ServerFault in the comments pointing out that SNI can cause this issue. I found that elsewhere in this java application it was being disabled:
System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");

correcting this by setting it to true fixes my immediate issue.
